# Get latest node with specific value of node property

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a schema where `Product` contains many revisions `ProductRevision` which say in which status the product is and it is connected to specific `ProductParts` configuration with nodes for each `Part`. Each `Part` can be used in many `ProductParts` and each `ProductParts` is used usually in three revisions (status `New`, `Tested` and `Production`). If `ProductParts` is changed, a new revision is created with status `New` and connected with previons last revision.

I have there also shortcuts like relationships `LATEST`, `LATEST_NEW`, `LATEST_TESTED` and `LATEST_PRODUCTION` which connect `Product` directly with latest node of revision, latest node of revision in status `New`, etc.

Command for creating simple example is here

```
CREATE (p:Product {Name:"Test1"})-[:REVISION {Created:datetime()}]-> 
(pr1:ProductRevision {Status:"New", Created:datetime()})-[:USING]->(pp:ProductParts)
CREATE (pp)-[:CONTAINS]->(p1:Part {Id:1})
CREATE (pp)-[:CONTAINS]->(p2:Part {Id:2})
CREATE (pr1)-[:REVISION {Created:datetime()}]->(pr2:ProductRevision {Status:"Tested", Created:datetime()})-[:USING]->(pp)
CREATE (pr2)-[:REVISION {Created:datetime()}]->(pr3:ProductRevision {Status:"Production", Created:datetime()})-[:USING]->(pp)
CREATE (ppChanged:ProductParts)
CREATE (ppChanged)-[:USING]->(p1)
CREATE (ppChanged)-[:USING]->(p3:Part {Id:3})
CREATE (pr3)-[:REVISION {Created:datetime()}]->(pr4:ProductRevision {Status:"New", Created:datetime()})-[:USING]->(ppChanged)
CREATE (pr4)-[:REVISION {Created:datetime()}]->(pr5:ProductRevision {Status:"Tested", Created:datetime()})-[:USING]->(ppChanged)
CREATE (p)-[:LATEST {Created:datetime()}]->(pr5)
CREATE (p)-[:LATEST_NEW {Created:datetime()}]->(pr4)
CREATE (p)-[:LATEST_TESTED {Created:datetime()}]->(pr5)
CREATE (p)-[:LATEST_PRODUCTION {Created:datetime()}]->(pr3)
```

So and I need to get chain like `(Product)-(ProductParts)-(Part)` where `ProductParts` is connected through latest revision in specific status, e.g. `Tested` or `Production`.

I wanted to use shortcuts relationships `LATEST_*` but it doesn't work as I expected. I tried query like

```
MATCH (p:Product)-[:LATEST_TESTED|LATEST_PRODUCTION]-(pr:ProductRevision)--(pp:ProductParts)--(pa:Part)
WITH *, max(pr.Created) as prc
RETURN p,pr,prc,pp,pa
```

but it returns all `ProductParts` with specific status not only the last one.

If I don't return `pr` relation between `Product` and `ProductParts` missing.

Exists any way how to get following result when I want latest revision with specific status `Tested` or `Production`

```
(:Product {Name: "Test"}) --> (:ProductRevision {Status:"Tested"}) --> (:ProductParts) --> (:Part {Id:1})
.                                                                                      \-> (:Part {Id:3})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split your request in two parts:
- First, get the latest `ProductRevision` you are interested in
- Second, get all `ProductParts` and Parts related to the `ProductRevision`

```
MATCH (p:Product)-[:LATEST_TESTED|LATEST_PRODUCTION]-(pr:ProductRevision)
WITH p, pr
ORDER BY pr.Created DESC
LIMIT 1
MATCH (pr)--(pp:ProductParts)--(pa:Part)
RETURN p, pr, pp, pa
```

The first `MATCH` gets the latest `ProductRevision` by ordering the results descending and keeping only the first result
The second `MATCH` gets the rest of the information you need.

Comment: It works only for one `Product`. If I have more nodes it returns only one. But your answer help me to find a right way and finally I changed `LIMIT 1` to `WITH p, head(collect(pr)[..1]) as lpr` and it works as I need. Thanks!

Comment: Ok great. I didn't catch that from your example nodes. Well done.